# Is there an idiomatic way to "merge by index" lists of the same length?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider

```
listMerge[list1_, list2_] := Thread[({#1, #2}) &[list1, list2]]
listMerge[{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}] (* {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}} *)
```

Is there a built-in function in Mathematica that already does what `listMerge` does (ideally one that handles more than 2 arguments)?

Answer (score 10):

Just use `Transpose`

```
listMerge[list1_, list2_] := Transpose[{list1, list2}]

listMerge[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

> {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}}

Or

```
Transpose[{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}]
```

> {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}}

```
listMerge[list_] := Transpose[list]
listMerge[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
```

> {{1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}}

Answer (score 8):

You can define `listMerge` as the [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) of `Thread` and `List` (or `Transpose` and `List`)

```
ClearAll[listMerge1, listMerge2, listMerge3, listMerge4, listMerge5]
listMerge1 =  Thread @* List;
listMerge2 =  Transpose @* List;
listMerge3 = Thread[{##}] &;
listMerge4 = Transpose[{##}] &;
listMerge5 = Join[## & @@ Map[List, {##}, {-1}], 2] &;

listMerge1[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}

```
Equal @@ (#[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}] & /@ 
  {listMerge1, listMerge2, listMerge3, listMerge4, listMerge5})
```

> True

```
listMerge1[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}]
```

> {{1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}}

```
Equal @@ (#[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}] & /@ 
  {listMerge1, listMerge2, listMerge3, listMerge4, listMerge5})
```

> True